# Play Framewok 1.2.4 : custom staticDir

Tags: java, playframework

I am using Play Framework 1.2.4 and I want to add a custom staticDir in my routes file.

My routes file contains the public folder (following the  [play framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/routes))
`GET    /public/    staticDir:public`

And I want to add another staticDir. 
To do so, I added `GET    /test/    staticDir:test` to my routes file.

My project folders look like :

- /app
- /test(with subfolders javascripts, css, ...)
- /public (with subfolders javascripts, css, ...)

But when I try to access to a file contained in that folder (with http://localhost/test/myJsFile.js) I get a TemplateExecutionException caused by a NullPointerException.

Did I forgot something ? Or do I have to handle this new staticDir in my java solution ?

Comment: Don't use test dir. It is for test cases. Try with different dir name.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I also tried with other names without success.